# How to set conkys window width?

Tags: conky

I use the following .conkyrc: 

The key Question: How can I set the window width, so that I could have a wider "window" for my stuff?

```
background yes
use_xft yes
xftfont Terminus:size=8
xftalpha 0.8
update_interval 3.0
total_run_times 0
double_buffer yes
own_window yes
own_window_type override
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
minimum_size 0 0
draw_shades yes
draw_outline no
draw_borders yes
stippled_borders 8
border_margin 0
border_width 0
default_color ffffff
default_shade_color black
default_outline_color ffffff
alignment top_left
# gap_x - 1280x800 = 1105; 1024x768 = 820
gap_x 1513
gap_y 5
no_buffers yes
uppercase no
cpu_avg_samples 2
net_avg_samples 2
override_utf8_locale yes
use_spacer yes
text_buffer_size 4096
TEXT
```

Thanks for any suggestions :\

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Conky has [excellent documentation](http://conky.sourceforge.net/config_settings.html):

> ```
> maximum_width   Maximum width of window
> minimum_size    Minimum size of window
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Having similar issues, don't forget to reboot once you made adjustments to the conky config, or restart it. Otherwise you will not see the updated changes.

Comment: You don't need to reboot your machine to see updates to conky configs. In fact, conky seems to use inotify to ensure that an edited configuration file is automatically loaded and the updated conky displayed.

Comment: Yes, but it will only work every second time when `.conkyrc` is edited with `gedit`, as I've found out. So you edit it, save the file - nothing happens. You edit it again (a pseudo-edit might do)...and all of a sudden, conky *will* detect the config file change and restart automatically.

Comment: Even if it is not well said, sometimes auto-reload of conky will not take into account the size changes. So he is right saying that you might have to restart conky process. I tried every conky resize command combination before founding this useful answer.

Comment: I modified `mininum_width` in my /etc/conky/conky.conf and reboot, but the size of conky window doesn't change, does anyone know what I should do?